# Why and how to get rid of NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, slider, nullreferenceexception

```
namespace WindowsPhoneApp
{

    Class MainPage()
    {
        private void ProcentSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            ShowSliderValue.Text = ProcentSlider.Value.ToString(); //<-- NullReferenceException
        }

    }
}
```

I can't reference the value of the Slider control to the TextBox control...

Comment: Is ProcentSlider null, or ProcentSlider.Value null?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the line and determine whether ProcentSlider or Value are null - it could be either

Comment: He is handling the `ValueChanged-Event` of the `ProcentSlider`...so I think the `ShowSliderValue` has never been initialized.

Comment: How to see that? Sorry I'm still new to C#

Comment: Put a `if (ProcentSlider.HasValue)` around setting the Text property of ShowSliderValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - it might be because the ShowSliderValue is running in a different thread.. bit of a guess though.

```
private void ProcentSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ShowSliderValue.Text = ProcentSlider.Value.ToString();));
}
```

or maybe this?

```
private void ProcentSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    var slider = (ProcentSlider)sender;
    ShowSliderValue.Text = slider.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This worked :D Thank you! Sadly I can't upvote because of some reputation requirement...

Comment: Can anyone explain what actually you are doing?

Comment: @user1171498 - that depends on which one worked, the first or second code snippet? Also, you can't upvote, but you can mark the answer as "the answer" by clicking on the "tick" below the up/downvote.

Comment: @user1171498 which worked? I'll remove the answer that didn't.